# Insert into Doubly LinkedList

Tags: java, doubly-linked-list

I am tring to insert string into doubly linked list in reverse  order. But I am not sure how can I maintain the insertion order in reverse order.

This is my below code.

```
theList.insertReverseLexicographicalOrder("B");
theList.insertReverseLexicographicalOrder("A");
theList.insertReverseLexicographicalOrder("H");
theList.insertReverseLexicographicalOrder("D");
theList.insertReverseLexicographicalOrder("E");

public void insertReverseLexicographicalOrder(String dd) {
    Link newLink = new Link(dd);
    if (isEmpty()){
        last = newLink;
    }           
        first.previous = newLink;
    }
    newLink.next = first;
    first = newLink;
}
```

Any suggestions will be appreciated with some code based on my solution..

Answer (score 1):

Well you assume that its already in reverse order, so you're going to need some sort of loop through until you find where it should go.. i.e.

Z, Y, X, W, L, K, A

if you're inserting M, then you should loop until you find L, which is lexicographically larger than M, and therefore insert it there. Because the nodes have previous pointers, insertion shouldn't be too hard to figure out on your own

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It will be really great to understand if you can post some code based on my solution.

Answer (score 0):

How to insert a node into a linked list:

1. If the list is empty, the new node will become the first, and if we keep track of that, also the last
2. Otherwise find the position where to insert, there are three possibilities,
   a) the new node has to be inserted before the first
   b) the new node has to be inserted after the last
   c) the new node has to be inserted between two existing nodes
3. Update the appropriate references, that may be `first`, `last` and some `next` and `previous` fields, depending on where it has to be inserted

```
if (first == null) {
    // the list is empty so far
} else
```

To find the position, first compare the data with the first node's data to see whether it has to be inserted before the first node.

```
if (newLink.iData.compareTo(first.iData) > 0) {
    // put newLink before first
} else {
```

You have to keep a focus on some list node. Follow the list from the start until you reach the point of insertion:

```
    Link focus = first; // focus first node
    while(focus.next != null && newLink.iData.compareTo(focus.next.iData) < 0) {
        focus = focus.next;
    }
    // now you have to insert the new value behind focus, left as exercise
    if (focus.next == null) {
        // newLink becomes the last node in the list
    } else {
       // newLink has to be inserted between focus and focus.next
    }
}
```

Then insert. Beware of edge cases, inserting at the front and the end are slightly different.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But I am not able to understand how should I move forward with the code you have provided. It will be really great if you can post some solution based on my code. Thanks for your help.

Comment: How to move forward is in the post (I've fixed a C-ism now). It doesn't yet handle the case of the empty list, but that's easy. Since it's homework, I don't want to give too many details.

Comment: I have updated the code as per your suggestions but still its not working.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to look through the list comparing each of the elements. Stop when you find the  element that goes after the element you are trying to insert. I suggest you implement the compareTo method in your node class: http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=10
and use it to make the comparisons

Good Luck.